# rxjs firstValueFrom never resolve

Tags: node.js, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create something like an event loop on RxJs, I use `firstValueFrom` as a gate to wait for all events to be processed before going further.
The goal is to have a nodejs service running and reacting on various events, processing those and be able to gracefully shut down when commanded.

I can see the behaviour I cannot explain to myself - when the exit condition *could be met* - everything works as expected: events are issued by issuers and handled by handlers.

However, when I remove the possibility of the exit event appearing - the code immediately exit after `rx.firstValueFrom` call.

The code:

```
import * as rx from "rxjs";
import * as op from "rxjs/operators";

async function foo(): Promise<string> {
    console.log("1");
    const s = new rx.ReplaySubject<string>();
    const t = rx.timer(1000)
        .pipe(
            op.take(3),
            op.map(x => x.toString()),
            op.endWith("exit"),
        );

    const exitObserver = s.asObservable()
        .pipe(
            op.mergeWith(t),
            op.filter(x => x === "exit")
        );
    console.log("2");
    const firstValue = await rx.firstValueFrom(exitObserver);
    console.log("3");
    return firstValue;
}

foo()
    .then(x => console.log(`result: ${x}`))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .finally(() => console.log('finally'))
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
result: exit
finally
```

Which is expected.

Altered code with expected indefinite loop ("exit" event is commented out):

```
import * as rx from "rxjs";
import * as op from "rxjs/operators";

async function foo(): Promise<string> {
    console.log("1");
    const s = new rx.ReplaySubject<string>();
    const t = rx.timer(1000)
        .pipe(
            op.take(3),
            op.map(x => x.toString()),
            //op.endWith("exit"),
        );

    const exitObserver = s.asObservable()
        .pipe(
            op.mergeWith(t),
            op.filter(x => x === "exit")
        );
    console.log("2");
    const firstValue = await rx.firstValueFrom(exitObserver);
    console.log("3");
    return firstValue;
}

foo()
    .then(x => console.log(`result: ${x}`))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
    .finally(() => console.log('finally'))
```

Output:

```
1
2
```

Which is not expected. I expect this code to work indefinitely waiting for the "exit event".
There are no error messages. I use typescript 4.3.5, node v14.15.4, RxJs 7.4.0.

**My questions are**:

1. Why does the altered code doesn't go into indefinite loop waiting for non-existing message?
2. How to create an indefinite loop with RxJs?

Comment: is this something to do with the top level async foo function?

Answer (score 2):

1. It cannot write 3 to the output, because it is still waiting for first value from exitObservable. You have a filter there, therefore it never happen. The term of indefinite loop is in the RxJS world probably misleading.
2. You can use `takeUntil` to achieve your goal.

```js
const {Subject} = rxjs;
const {filter, takeUntil} = rxjs.operators;

const actions$ = new Subject();

actions$
  .pipe(
    filter(action => action !== 'exit'),
    takeUntil(actions$.pipe(
      filter(action => action === 'exit')
    ))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: action => console.log(`result: ${action}`),
    error: error => console.error(e),
    complete: () => console.log('exit'),
  });
  
actions$.next('first');
actions$.next('second');
actions$.next('exit');
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@^7/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why does the altered code doesn't go into indefinite loop waiting for non-existing message?

It does. That's why

```ts
console.log("3");
return firstValue;
```

never gets run. You never log a result, etc.

---

> How to create an indefinite loop with RxJs?

Not sure what you mean. The following code will print out a number every 5 seconds for forever. Is that what you mean by `indefinite loop`?

```ts
interval(5000).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say here. 1. - it does not, the process is terminating after "2" in the console. I may use the wrong word here - infinite, not indefinite loop. you know, the one you should specifically break.

Comment: @Dmitrii Yes. Infinite. It will wait there *for forever* since it never gets a first value

Comment: I feel like I am failing to communicate an issue here. this code: ```async function cat(): Promise<void> {
    const dog = await new Promise<string>(resolve => {
    });
    console.log(dog);
}
cat();``` when run from console with node terminates immediately but I expect it to run an infinite loop, how is that?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not understanding how that should be a loop. Or even what you're waiting for. V8 and node will terminate once the event loop is empty. Which might mean that your continuations never get called... maybe that's tripping you up?

Comment: yep, that was it